# Windows Phone Mvvm Light Navigate between Views

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8, mvvm

I'm new on Windows phone. I want to create an application but actually i have a problem with the Binding command.

I want on click , to change the view

In my homepage i have 2 buttons : Login / Register in my MainPage.xaml on the View Folder

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FF563AA0" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Grid.Background>

        <ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentViewModel}" />

        <Button 
            Command="{Binding ConnexionViewCommand}"
            x:Name="Connexion_button" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
            Margin="90,308,0,0"
            Content="Login" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top" 
            Width="282"/>
        <Button 
            Command="{Binding InscriptionViewCommand}"
            x:Name="Create_account" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
            Margin="90,446,0,0"
            Content="Create Account" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top" 
            Width="282"/>
    </Grid>

</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

I have 3 files in my folder View : ConnexionView.xaml and InscriptionView.xaml , and the MainPage.xaml

5 files in my folder ViewModel : ConnexionViewModel.cs , InscriptionViewModel.cs, MainPageViewModel.cs, MainViewModel.cs and ViewModelLocator.cs

I try to Follow this example but i don't understand a lot.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/323187/MVVMLight-Using-Two-Views

i add this code in my MainViewModel.cs but i don't know what i have to do now.

```
namespace TeysserApp.ViewModel
{
    public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private ViewModelBase _currentViewModel;

        readonly static ConnexionViewModel _ConnexionViewModel = new ConnexionViewModel();
        readonly static InscriptionViewModel _InscriptionViewModel = new InscriptionViewModel();
        readonly static MainPageViewModel _MainPageViewModel = new MainPageViewModel();


        public ViewModelBase CurrentViewModel
        {
            get
            {
                return _currentViewModel;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_currentViewModel == value)
                    return;
                _currentViewModel = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("CurrentViewModel");
            }
        }
        public ICommand ConnexionViewCommand { get; private set; }
        public ICommand InscriptionViewCommand { get; private set; }

        public MainViewModel()
        {
            CurrentViewModel = MainViewModel._MainPageViewModel;
            ConnexionViewCommand = new RelayCommand(() => ExecuteCommandViewCommand());
            InscriptionViewCommand = new RelayCommand(() => ExecuteInscriptionViewCommand());
        }
        private void ExecuteConnexionViewCommand()
        {
            CurrentViewModel = MainViewModel._ConnexionViewModel;
        }

        private void ExecuteSecondViewCommand()
        {
            CurrentViewModel = MainViewModel._InscriptionViewModel;
        }

    }
}
```

Here my ViewModelLocator.cs

```
namespace TestApp.ViewModel
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This class contains static references to all the view models in the
    /// application and provides an entry point for the bindings.
    /// <para>
    /// See http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm
    /// </para>
    /// </summary>
    public class ViewModelLocator
    {
        static ViewModelLocator()
        {
            ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);

            if (ViewModelBase.IsInDesignModeStatic)
            {
                // SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IDataService, Design.DesignDataService>();
            }
            else
            {
                // SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IDataService, DataService>();
            }

            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<MainViewModel>();
            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<ConnexionViewModel>();
            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<InscriptionViewModel>();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the Main property.
        /// </summary>
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Performance",
            "CA1822:MarkMembersAsStatic",
            Justification = "This non-static member is needed for data binding purposes.")]
        public MainViewModel Main
        {
            get { return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<MainViewModel>(); }
        }
        public ConnexionViewModel ConnexionView
        {
            get { return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ConnexionViewModel>(); }
        }
        public InscriptionViewModel InscriptionView
        {
            get { return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<InscriptionViewModel>(); }
        }
    }
}
```

Here my App.xaml

```
<Application
    x:Class="TeysserApp.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:views="clr-namespace:TeysserApp.Views"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:TeysserApp.ViewModels"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone">

<Application.Resources>
    <vm:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator" />
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:ConnexionViewModel}">
            <view:ConnexionView />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:InscriptionViewModel}">
            <view:InscriptionView />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ResourceDictionary>
    <local:LocalizedStrings xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TeysserApp" x:Key="LocalizedStrings"/>
</Application.Resources>

    <Application.ApplicationLifetimeObjects>
        <!--Objet requis qui gère les événements de durée de vie pour l'application-->
        <shell:PhoneApplicationService
            Launching="Application_Launching" Closing="Application_Closing"
            Activated="Application_Activated" Deactivated="Application_Deactivated"/>
    </Application.ApplicationLifetimeObjects>

</Application>
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [MVVM Light 5](http://blog.galasoft.ch/posts/2014/10/announcing-mvvm-light-v5-for-windows-and-xamarin) Laurent has introduce `NavigationService`

```
public ViewModelLocator()
{
    ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);

    var navigationService = this.CreateNavigationService();

    SimpleIoc.Default.Register<INavigationService>(() => navigationService);

    SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IDialogService, DialogService>();

    SimpleIoc.Default.Register<MainViewModel>();
    SimpleIoc.Default.Register<DetailsViewModel>();
}

private INavigationService CreateNavigationService()
{
  var navigationService = new NavigationService();
  navigationService.Configure("Details", typeof(DetailsPage));
  // navigationService.Configure("key1", typeof(OtherPage1));

//From a working project.
navigationService.Configure("tnc", new System.Uri("/Views/TncAgreement.xaml", System.UriKind.Relative));


 return navigationService;
}
```

**Your ViewModel**

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{

 private INavigationService navigationService;

 public RelayCommand DetailsCommand { get; set; }

 public MainViewModel(INavigationService navigationService)
 {
     this.navigationService = navigationService;

      //Show Terms and condition agreement;
      navigationService.NavigateTo("tnc");

     DetailsCommand = new RelayCommand(() =>
    {
        navigationService.NavigateTo("Details", "My data");
    });
 }
}
```

Similar SO [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28968560/1876572)

Comment: i don't know why Frame.navigate or NavigationService do not work.
I have this following error for my Frame.navigate : Cannot Convert System.String to System.Uri.

For my NavigationService.Navigate : An object reference is required for the property. The method or the non-static field "NavigationService.Navigate (Uri)

Comment: I have updated the answer , if you still experience problem pls add with a detailed information about which line throw the exception and so on

Answer (score 0):

When you press the `Connexion` button the method `ExecuteFirstViewCommand()` is run however this doesn't exists, you need to change the lambda operation method `ExecuteConnexionViewCommand()`. If that doesn't solve it then could you debug the code at run-time and see if the `CurrentViewModel` is being updated.

[image]

**Make sure it is encapsulated in a resource dictionary!**

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Comment: i can't put this following code because that said : DataType is not recognized or is not accessible.

Comment: Could you show what you have put in your App.Xaml please

Comment: The problem is ( i think ) the DataType.
i have this following code when i put datatemplate datatype in my App.xaml : 

 DataType is not recognized or is not accessible.

Comment: Hmm, which specific part isn't accessible p.s make sure you have checked those methods mentioned in my answer as that will cause it not to work as well.

Comment: "InscriptionView/ConnexionView is not supported in a Windows Phone Silverlight project."
Do you think the problem is the silverlight project?

Comment: That might well be the case, I haven't worked with silverlight only WPF. If you have tried everything I have mentioned then I think the problem is beyond my scope. Good luck with finding it, I'm sure you'll figure it out.

Comment: Do you think i can put "Frame.navigate or NavigationService.Navigate in my ExecuteConnexionViewCommand() / ExecuteInscriptionViewCommand() function ?

Comment: Cannot Convert System.String to System.Uri  
when i put : Frame.Navigate(typeof(ConnexionView));