# Navigation in WPF MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

How to navigate from one window to other using NavigationService in locator. I tried

```
var navigationService = new NavigationService();
```

The above line showing error. It tells `navigationservice doesnot takes zero arguements`

Comment: You need to provide alot more information. What is `NavigationService`? Is it from some toolkit?

Comment: GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Views

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like the comments mention you provided not much information but maybe following question helps:
[MVVM Light 5.0: How to use the Navigation service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28966819/mvvm-light-5-0-how-to-use-the-navigation-service)

Or maybe you can look at the docs or posts from the author.
http://www.mvvmlight.net/doc/nav1.cshtml

or... if you use google you find blog posts like this...
https://marcominerva.wordpress.com/2014/10/10/navigationservice-in-mvvm-light-v5/

HTH