# MVVM Light Toolkit NavigationService implementation for WPF using a Frame

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

I am starting to learn MVVM and am trying to use the MVVM Light Toolkit in a WPF project. In the app I will need to navigate to numerous pages and navigate back also. I know I need a `NavigationService` that I should register with the `SimpleIoc`.

However, it appears the toolkit doesn't have an implementation of a `NavigationService` for use in WPF, only offering an `INavigationService` interface. In my `MainWindow` I have a `Frame` that I think should deal with the navigation, so my thinking is the `NavigationService` class should delegate to this in some way?

Can anyone supply, or point me in the direction of a WPF implementation of `NavigationService` class using a frame for me to understand it better? So far my searching has not produced anything for WPF, just stuff tailored to Silverlight which I no nothing about.

Like I say I'm just starting to get to grips with this MVVM stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MvvmLight doesn't provide an implementation of the `INavigationService` for WPF. This is because there is no standard navigation mechanism available in WPF as Laurent Bugnion - the creator of MvvmLight - has stated here: http://blog.galasoft.ch/posts/2014/10/announcing-mvvm-light-v5-for-windows-and-xamarin/

The Frame control has a NavigationService property. There is an example of how you could implement the `INavigationInterface` in WPF available here:

[MVVM Light 5.0: How to use the Navigation service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28966819/mvvm-light-5-0-how-to-use-the-navigation-service)

Comment: Hi @mm8 , this looks exactly what I was looking for! Thank you.