# WPF ViewBox blocks VisualTreeHelper search

Tags: wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light, viewbox, visualtreehelper

I have tried this Navigation Service approach (View First) for MVVM-Light WPF
https://stackoverflow.com/a/28968560/5272185

I realized that the VisualTreeHelper search for the Frame element does not find the Frame if the Frame is located inside a ViewBox.

Is there a good explanation of such strange behaviour?
Is it possible to work around it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the example code in the link was the problem.
If you run into this type of problem I recommend to read the following from Josh Smith 
[Understanding the Visual Tree and Logical Tree in WPF](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21495/Understanding-the-Visual-Tree-and-Logical-Tree-in)

The code he provides in the [Research Tool project](https://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WpfElementTrees/ElementTreeComparison.zip) successfully found the ContentControl also when it is inside a ViewBox. I modified his code to return the content control. Problem solved.